# ¿Por qué se sobreescriben los valores de un objecto en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Estoy tratando de asignar los valores de varios inputs pero siempre se queda asignado los del último valor, vale destacar que este procedimiento lo estoy haciendo dinámico para luego pasarlo por JSON.

Por ejemplo este es mi html:

```
<input type="text" name="Examen" value="Examen" />
<input type="text" name="TipoExamen" value="TipoExamen" />
<input type="text" name="FechaExamen" value="FechaExamen" />
<input type="text" name="Tema" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="TipoTema" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="IDTema" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="Pregunta" value="4" />
<input type="text" name="TipoPregunta" value="5" />
<input type="text" name="Tema" value="Tema2" />
<input type="text" name="TipoTema" value="TipoTema2" />
<input type="text" name="IDTema" value="IDTema2" />
<input type="text" name="Pregunta" value="Pregunta2" />
<input type="text" name="TipoPregunta" value="TipoPregunta2" />
```

Quiero que cuando detecte que el valor cambio no lo sobreescriba si no que lo agregue para así tener ambos datos

El valor de cada input lo obtengo con el siguiente código

```
var items = $("form :input").map(function (index, elm) {
    return { value: $(elm).val(), name: elm.name };
});
```

Cuando aplico `console.log(items)` me trae los siguientes valores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aqui todo marcha bien pero, el siguiente es donde se me esta presentando el problema con la sobre escritura

```
var cart = [];
var element = {};
for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    if (items[index].value != "") {
        switch(items[index].name) {
            case "Examen":
                    element.Examen = items[index].value;
                break;
            case "TipoExamen":
                element.TipoExamen = items[index].value;
                break;
            case "FechaExamen":
                element.FechaExamen = items[index].value;
                break;
            case "Tema":
                element.Tema = items[index].value;
                break;
            case "TipoTema":
                    element.TipoTema = items[index].value;
                break;
            case "IDTema":
                element.IDTema = items[index].value;
                break;
            case "Pregunta":
                element.Pregunta = items[index].value;
                break;
            case "TipoPregunta":
                element.TipoPregunta = items[index].value;
                break;
        }
        cart.push(element);
    }
}
```

Con este código lo trato de convertir como un objeto para luego pasarlo por JSON pero aquí es donde me sobrescribe todos los valores. Así es como me los muestra  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes poner tu código en jsbidn o jsfiddle para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Viendo las imágenes no entiendo donde esté el problema, ¿El primer pantallazo imprime `items` y el segundo imprime `element`? ¿Si es así dónde está el problema?

Comment: En la función de mapeo de JavaScript los argumentos son los siguientes **(valorActual,index,array)** y **NO (index,valorActual)**;

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vilfrack/nLe20onn/3/ aqui les dejo el jsfiddle

Comment: @juanvilla Tienes los datos de name y value; y aparte deseas obtener otro? o en todo caso deja un ejemplo de como deseas obtenerlo. gracias.

Comment: no, @Raul, explico que es lo que quiero, hay input que se están repitiendo que son los últimos 5, esos últimos 5 están sustituyendo a los anteriores y es lo que no quiero que pase, quiero me que muestren los anteriores juntos  con los últimos 5, asi tal cual como pase en la ultima imagen que inicia 0:Examen,FechaExamen,IDTema,Tema, TipoExamen,TipoPregunta,TipoTema, deberia salir otro que seria 1 : y los datos de los ultimos 5 valores

Comment: El tema es que se deben mostrar como el ultimo print porque así si los puedo recibir en el controlador con un list<> en c#. intente meter un array dentro del for pero me descuadra todo el formato

Answer (score 0):

Buenas muchachos ya logre hacerlo copio el codigo El html `

```
<input type="text" name="Examen" value="Examen" />
<input type="text" name="TipoExamen" value="TipoExamen" />
<input type="text" name="FechaExamen" value="FechaExamen" />

<input type="text" name="Tema" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="TipoTema" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="IDTema" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="Pregunta" value="4" />
<input type="text" name="TipoPregunta" value="5" />



<input type="text" name="Tema" value="Tema2" />
<input type="text" name="TipoTema" value="TipoTema2" />
<input type="text" name="IDTema" value="IDTema2" />
<input type="text" name="Pregunta" value="Pregunta2" />
<input type="text" name="TipoPregunta" value="TipoPregunta2" />

<input type="text" name="Tema" value="TemaLOL" />
<input type="text" name="TipoTema" value="TipoTemaLOL" />
<input type="text" name="IDTema" value="IDTemaLOL" />
<input type="text" name="Pregunta" value="PreguntaLOL" />
<input type="text" name="TipoPregunta" value="TipoPreguntaLOL" />

<button id="bnt" type="button">boton</button>
```

Y el js

```
  function Examenes(Examen, TipoExamen, FechaExamen, Tema, TipoTema, IDTema, Pregunta, TipoPregunta) {
        this.Examen = Examen;
        this.TipoExamen = TipoExamen;
        this.FechaExamen = FechaExamen;
        this.Tema = Tema;
        this.TipoTema = TipoTema;
        this.IDTema = IDTema;
        this.Pregunta = Pregunta;
        this.TipoPregunta = TipoPregunta;
    }
    $('#bnt').click(function () {
        var items = $("form :input").map(function (index, elm) {

            return { value: $(elm).val(), name: elm.name };
        });
        var examenArreglo=[];
        var Examen, TipoExamen, FechaExamen, Tema, TipoTema, IDTema, Pregunta, TipoPregunta;

        $(items).each(function (index, value) {
            switch (value.name) {
                case "Examen":
                    Examen = value.value;
                    break;
                case "TipoExamen":
                    TipoExamen = value.value;
                    break;
                case "FechaExamen":
                    FechaExamen = value.value;
                    break;
                case "Tema":
                    Tema = value.value;
                    break;
                case "TipoTema":
                    TipoTema = value.value;
                    break;
                case "IDTema":
                    IDTema = value.value;
                    break;
                case "Pregunta":
                    Pregunta = value.value;
                    break;
                case "TipoPregunta":
                    TipoPregunta = value.value;
                    break;
            }

            if (Examen != undefined && TipoExamen != undefined && FechaExamen != undefined && Tema != undefined && TipoTema != undefined && IDTema != undefined && Pregunta != undefined && TipoPregunta != undefined) {
                var examen = new Examenes(Examen, TipoExamen, FechaExamen, Tema, TipoTema, IDTema, Pregunta, TipoPregunta);//para llamar al objeto
                examenArreglo.push(examen);
                Tema = undefined; TipoTema = undefined; IDTema = undefined; Pregunta = undefined; TipoPregunta = undefined;

            }
        });


        examenArreglo = JSON.stringify({ 'pregunta': examenArreglo });


        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Default/Create',
            data: examenArreglo,
            success: function () {
                $('#result').html('"PassThings()" successfully called.');
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                $('#result').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
```